# How to work on many changes at once in git?

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

I am used to Rational Team Concert.  I might be working on 5 or 6 unrelated code changes.  In RTC I just make changes, check them into different change sets to keep the changes separate, but at any given time my work space has the cumulative changes from all change sets.  (Unless of course I suspend one/some of them, but I rarely do that)

In git, my understanding is that for each unrelated change I should have a separate branch to make the changes there.  They get merged back to master or some other main branch eventually.   But my question is if I have 5 active changes going at once, and so 5 branches, and I want to run the cumulative changes in eclipse to debug, then as far as I can tell I have to make a new branch and merge all the separate feature branches to it. Then if I make more changes to 3 of of the 5 feature branches, I must remember to merge all those into the "cumulative" branch again in order to have a cumulative working set of files with all the latest changes.

Compared to my workflow in RTC this seems VERY cumbersome.... Perhaps I am going about this all wrong though... or perhaps there is a feature that makes this a bit less of a manual process?  (i.e. some command to select a bunch of branches and with a single action merge them all into a new (or selected) branch.... and/or have the cumulative branch somehow know that it's supposed to be synced/merged from the 5 feature branches and so I could just tell it to basically go fetch all those changes and merge in one command)

Does anyone have any advice?  Should I be going about this a different way?  Is there a command/set up I just need to know about?

Thanks!

Comment: @Philippe Apologies - I wrote out RTC as Rational Team Concert now. :-) Though I would guess that if you don't recognize "RTC" then there is little benefit from you having read "Rational Team Concert" instead.  After all if you don't know ubiquitous short name for an SCM then seeing it called by it's full name is not going to cause you to suddenly be familiar with the workflow of it. And the only value in me mentioning RTC is for the people familiar with RTC as they would know how RTC works and might better understand my workflow mindset.  And all those people would recognize "RTC". :-)

Comment: @Philippe I didn't say my previous work flow won't work with git. :-) I said that it seems that doing things in my current way would be cumbersome.  And I am looking for advice on how to work efficiently with git :-)

by my current way I mean "always have all cumulative changes in my active working set" and "still commit everything as separate specific-purpose commits"

The only way I can figure to do this now with my limited understanding of git requires me to constantly to a lot of manual merging many feature branches into a "cumulative working branch" every time I want to run it.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm not sure how you could possibly consider me to have "lashed out"... I literally apologized and made the change he asked for.  I then politely explained my reasoning with many smiles to ensure it was clear I was trying to be friendly and polite.  Is it considered lashing out just to explain my reasoning?  Philippe did start his comment with a sarcastic remark instead of politely asking me to clarify RTC. It seems fair I should be allowed to explain myself. :-) In any case - as requested I will try to be more explicit in the future.

Comment: @ben, you did well :) It's hard to misinterpret people through written text (on both sides), and remember that for many people English is a second language. Some times there is an argument here in the comments over nothing while both sides agree to the same thing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest not trying to use another tool's workflow with git, but learn how you can use git in its own way.

I often do what you say as well with git, and quite easily! It's true that in git, you can't prematurely mark some uncommitted change as belonging to different future commits. You can only do so (with `git add`) for one commit. But as it turns out, there is rarely any need to build multiple commits at the same time.

As a matter of fact, you don't need to separate your changes into uncommitted-commits (git's term is to *stage* the change) until the moment you actually want to commit them. At that point, you can happily use `git add` (especially with the extremely useful `--patch` option (`-p` for short)) to separate the changes into meaningful commits.

With RTC, you are assigning a set of files to each change set (and possibly move them around later), but while they are not "committed", you really just have a bunch of dirty files you are working with. With git, that's exactly what you do. You make a bunch of files dirty, and only at the time of commit decide what changes belong together.

As an example, here are two situations I often find myself in and how I deal with them:

#### Situation 1: Interrupted Work

- Work on feature A
- Realize you need to fix bug B

Given that you are still in the middle of feature A, you may want to fix B without A muddling the code. In that case:

```
$ git stash
# work on B, test it
$ git add <files>
$ git commit
$ git stash pop
```

Alternatively, you may want to fix B while A is half-working. In that case:

```
# work on B
$ git add -p    # select changes related to B to be committed
$ git commit
# continue working on A
```

#### Situation 2: Multiple Features

Normally, when working on multiple features, you use a branch for each. This lets you (1) commit work for each feature often, (2) have the commits of each feature together and (3) be able to send a pull request for each feature separately. You don't test multiple half-written features together.

However, on occasion you may actually be working on multiple simple things at the same time (each of which require just one commit), or even more often, you may be working on multiple changes for the sake of one feature, but you may want to separate them into multiple commits for clarity. In my case, I almost always have debug logs and such that I don't want to commit, so I want to separate the changes-to-be-committed from the debug logs.

In all these case, the solution is simple: `git add --patch`.

```
# work on multiple things
$ git add -p
$ git commit    # first logical change
$ git add -p
$ git commit    # second logical change
$ git add -p
$ git commit    # third logical change
# you are left with what shouldn't be committed yet
```

---

In summary, until you are actually ready to commit something, you don't need to separate changes into "change sets". More often than not, you may find yourself touching the same file for multiple reasons, so you couldn't have really put that in any specific change set anyway. Imagine if feature A touches files X and Y, and feature B touches files Y and Z. What do you do with Y in RTC?

So with git, what you do is to extract what needs to be committed (with `git add --patch`, you can take specific changes from a file, possibly committing only parts of it) *at the time you want to make that commit*.

As always with git, commit often and make each commit as simple as possible (each commit should mark one coherent change). This would prevent you from going insane trying to separate 20 features coded over 1 month without committing anything.

Comment: Thanks!  This is super helpful! :-) I like the way you frame it that I am just waiting to split the changes into sets until later.  A couple questions though.

1. Do you know how to do "add -p" in egit?  I will be using in eclipse and would prefer gui interface if possible.  
2. One thing I like about RTC and checking in change sets is that my partial work is always on the server.  If I just keep dirty local files until I am done and ready to commit I don't have server backup.  Can I get around this in some way?

Comment: 1. I always use the terminal, so sorry, I don't know. 2. "Commit often" is the git way.

Comment: At work, we have to use Perforce, and I can imagine RTC is quite similar. Believe me, the only reason I would need my files "saved" on the server with Perforce is that it makes it impossible to commit often and move on, so at times I even have a feature I've been working on for weeks, which needs another week for review etc before I can actually submit it. With git, I commit so often, I barely have any dirty code by the end of each day, so I also never feel that I need any server to save my work. Like I said, git is a very different system, don't worry, overtime you'll learn how to best use it

Comment: Thanks!  I am a bit confused though.... it sounded like you were saying I just leave all the changes co-mingled in my active workspace, and then just pick out specific files to commit in separate commits when I am ready.  This sounds like the opposite of 'commit often'.  (Not trying to argue - trying to understand what I am missing :-) )  I *want* to commit often as I like to have things saved.  Curious also what you mean by not needing server to save your work?  I worry about hard drive failure... (my HD just failed a couple months ago but luckily everything was checked into server)

Comment: @Ben, one feature of Git might help you: when you check out a branch in Git, it tries to "fuse" uncommitted changes with what the branch contains. So if you really want to simulate RTC's behaviour, fork N temporary branches off the current point and switch between them freely while having uncommitted changes -- staging them selectively and committing like @Shabaz said. Then push these branches out; if you like, push a branch after each commit on it. You can use a prefix for the remote branch when pushing to clearly mark a branch as temporary--like `git push origin feature1:tmp/feature1`.

Comment: @Ben, when you're ready with your disparate feature branches, simply merge them into the mainline or may be rebase and then merge (depending on how you'd like the resulting history to look like). You can then delete those temporary remote branches by "pushing nothng" to them: like `git push origin :tmp/feature1 :tmp/feature2 ...`.

Comment: @Ben, to explain, Git does not anything like RTC has in this regard out of the box simply due to the fact Git is a DVCS--where "D" is for "Distributed": sharing history with other repositories always requires an explicit action, and Git has everything you need exactly to support disconnected operation rather than trying to deliver what you churn out to some remote repository as fast as possible. That is, it was created to reach different goals.

Comment: What @kostix said!

Comment: Also, when you commit often, in practice you could send a review/pull request for part of each feature as they are done, so the number of unmerged branches you usually end up with rarely gets more than a few. So while in theory it sounds difficult to work on 20 unmerged features for a long time, that's not what happens in practice, again, because you commit often, and since each commit is meaningful and separate, you can also merge often (with master).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the way you deal with on git is correct. But it’s not cumbersome after you adapt to git’s behavior—it just makes every change traceable.

If  you make more changes to 3 of 5 feature branches, so you need to merge them into cumulative branch. There have some graphical stuffs that you will find which branches need to merge obviously, any one of below works:

```
gitk --all

git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all
```

Comment: thanks!  Do you know how I find that graph in egit?  :-)

Comment: The graph is made by history, so you can't edit it directly. If you want to make changes for history commit, you can try `git filter-branch`. If you just want to edit for yourself, you can use `git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all` and then copy the grap.